# Characterize all left inverses of a matrix $A\in\mathbb R^{m\times n}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, pseudoinverse

Characterize all left inverses of a matrix $A\in\mathbb R^{m\times n}$.

*Note this for reference*, we have characterized all right inverse of the matrix $A$. Observe that we solve for $AA_R=I_m$. Then $A_R$ exists $\iff$ $\mathcal R(I_m)\subseteq \mathcal R(A) \iff AA^+I_m = I_m \iff$ rank($A$) = $m$ $\iff$ $A$ is onto. Thus a right inverse (need not be unique) is of the form for any $Y\in\mathbb R^{n\times m}$:
$$R = A^+I_m + (I_n - A^+A) Y = A^+ + (I_n - A^+A) Y$$

Using this as a guide, here is my attempt: We need to characterize $A_LA = I$ where $A_L$ indicates a left inverse of $A$. Well (following a similar reasoning), we take transpose $(A_LA)^T = I \iff A^T A_L^T = I$. Thus, $A_L^T$ exists $\iff \underbrace{\mathcal R(I)}_{=\mathcal N(I)^\perp} \subseteq \underbrace{\mathcal R(A^T)}_{=\mathcal N(A)^\perp} $ $\iff$ $\mathcal N(I)^\perp  \subseteq\mathcal N(A)^\perp$ $\underbrace{\iff}_{\text{take perp}}$ $\mathcal N(A) \subseteq \mathcal N(I)$ $\iff$ $IA^+A = I$ $\iff$ $A$ has a left inverse.

Then I am not sure where to go from here.

Here is a slightly different approach suggested by [Ben Grossmann](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/81360/ben-grossmann).

We have $A^TA_L^T = I$. Then from our knowledge of right inverses (above), $A_L^T$ is a right inverse of $A^T$ if and only if $A^T(A^T)^+I = I \iff$ rank($A^T$) = $n \iff A^T$ is onto. Thus a left inverse is of the form
$$A_L^T = (A^T)^+I_m + (I_n - (A^T)^+A^T) Y = (A^T)^+ +(I_n - (A^T)^+A^T) Y.$$
Then
$$\begin{equation}\begin{split}A_L = (A_L^T)^T &= ((A^+)^T +(I_n - (A^T)^+A^T) Y)^T \\ &= A^+ + Y^T\left(I-(A^+)^TA^T\right)^T \\ &=A^+ + Y^T(I- AA^+)\end{split}\end{equation}$$

Comment: You could use your results about right inverses directly by noting that $A_L$ is a left inverse to $A$ if and only if $A_L^T$ is a right inverse to $A^T$, where $A^T$ denotes the transpose of $A$.

Comment: I am thinking about it now @BenGrossmann

Comment: @BenGrossmann, would it then be the same as in the solution for right inverses but just replace all the $A$'s with $A^T$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $A$ has a left inverse, then $A$ as a linear map is injective.
For each subspace $W$ of $\mathbb R^m$ such that $\mathbb R^m = Im (A) \oplus W$, we define $A_L (x + y) = A^{-1}(x)$ for $x\in Im (A)$ and $y\in W$. One can check that $A_LA = \mathbb 1$ and $W=\ker(A_L)$.

On the other hand, if $A_L$ is a left inverse of $A$, then it can be shown that $\mathbb R^m = Im(A) \oplus \ker (A_L)$.

Therefore the left inverses of $A$ is in $1-1$ correspondence with the direct sum complements of $Im(A)$.

Comment: Can you clarify what $Im(A)$ means in this case as I am not familiar with this notation.

Comment: The image of $A$ (as a linear map)